# iPhone 3G: How to show locations around a fixed point?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, geolocation, gps, core-location

I have my current location fixed via CoreLocation. Now I want to get those locations (from an existing database), which are in the near (about 100 feet) of it.

How do I start?

---

Update: Here is a implementation of the Haversine formula: http://www.jaimerios.com/?p=39 (very useful)

Comment: Is this more of a "How do I calculate the distances between points" question, than a specific iPhone/Objective-C question?

Comment: No, I thought about how to solve this with CoreLocationo ;-)

Comment: Good one rijstellin. Because if it is, then Paul Betts has your answer, Stefan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CLLocation` provides a method for this:

`- (CLLocationDistance)getDistanceFrom:(const CLLocation *)location`

You'll need to have the latitude and longitude of each of your records, and then sort by the distance returned by this method.

Answer (score -1):

High school geometry FTW:

```
dist = sqrt(pow((x2-x1), 2) + pow((y2-y1), 2))
```

One of the things you can do to make this easier to SQL Query, is to split the map into "tiles", i.e. a 2km x 2km area, so that you can query down to the tile, then loop through the results using this formula.

Comment: But I can't apply this formula each of my locations (it's a database with round about 3500 locations). So I thought there would be a resource friendly method, which is included in CL.

Comment: This isn't a good way as the earth is spherical and you are preforming a direct line measurement for point A to point b.

Comment: He wants to know things that are within 100 feet of the current location, I don't think you have to worry about spherical distortion here :)